# Query related to Connection Id exchange between DTLS Client & Server using Californium Scandium core

Tags: dtls, californium

I am exploring on DTLS 1.2 using Californium-Scandium demo-apps projects.
It appears that Scandium-core [README.md](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/blob/master/scandium-core/README.md) supports the latest draft of [Connection Identifiers for DTLS 1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-tls-dtls-connection-id/).
According to [Connection Identifiers for DTLS 1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-tls-dtls-connection-id/), the CID exchange happens between the Client & the server if client and server wants to talk on based of Connection Id.
[image]
When I run the demo-apps of [Scandium Server](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/demo-apps/sc-dtls-example-server) & [Scandium Client](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/demo-apps/sc-dtls-example-client), I am not able to see the exchange of CID happening between the client and the server. Though I can see the Connection Id generation on Client as well Server side of DTLS. I have added the logger in the [Record.java](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/blob/master/scandium-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/scandium/dtls/Record.java) but the connection Id is always null in the loggers.
My question is whether the CID exchange logic between the DTLS Server and DTLS client is implemented in scandium-core API? If yes, please help me to find out the classes used for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 2.6.0, neither the ExampleDTLSClient nor the ExampleDTLSServer comes "out of the box" with CID enabled (but I will change that for 3.0 :-) ).

If you want to see that "out of the box" use the "cf-secure" demo. Start the client with "CID:0" for "support CID", and the server with "CID:6" to use a 6 bytes CID.

To enable CID for ExampleDTLSClient and ExampleDTLSServer, add to the DtlsConfigurationBuilder a

```
builder.setConnectionIdGenerator(new SingleNodeConnectionIdGenerator(cidLength));
```

Use cidLength 0 for the client (support) and 6 for the server (use 6 bytes).

Comment: Thank you so much Achim Kraus. I am able to see the exchange of cid using "cf-secure" demo project.         
Server Side:
CID generated is: CID=E360BA6BB1B0
19:09:27.712 INFO [DTLSFlight]: Prepare flight 6, using max. datagram size 1436, max. fragment size 16384 [mhm=false, mr=true]
Record Constructor : CID=14BDE17C4F


Client Side:
CID generated is: CID=14BDE17C4F
Record Constructor : CID=E360BA6BB1B0
generateAdditionalData fun: CID=E360BA6BB1B0
19:09:27.667 INFO [DTLSFlight]: Effective max. datagram size 1436
to byte array fun: CID=E360BA6BB1B0